# Pull the latest Employee and Manager Comments Based on Modified date

Tags: sql-server, ssms, date

I have a table `Comments` which is linked to the `Plan` table. Each time the user adds a comment on a specific plan, the `Comments` table is populated. This table stores the historical data. I need to pull out the latest record with the employee comments and the manager comments.

Comments Table schema is as shown below:

`EmpFK | PlanFK | Comments | ModifiedDate
  60       7     empCmnt1   13-04-2016
  61       7     mgrCmnt1   14-04-2016
  60       7     empCmnt2   18-04-2016
  61       7     mgrCmnt2   19-04-2016

  60       8     empcmnt1   01-03-2016`

Plan Table schema is as follows:

`PlanPK |  PlanName
  7         Name1
  8         Name2`

Employee Table Schema:

`EmpPK | MgrPK  | EmpName
  60      61       user1
  61               mgr1`

Here `60` is the empid and `61` is the mgrid. EmployeePK and the ManagerId column in the 'Employee' table gives the employee and manager details. Each employee will have only one manager. No higher lever consideration is needed in this scenario
Expected Result:

`empid  |  mgrid  | EmpCmnt  |  MgrCmnt  | ModifiedDate | planFK
  60         61     empCmnt2    mgrCmnt2   19-04-2016       7

  60         61     empcmnt1               01-03-2016       8`

Comment: Is there any designation in the employee table of who is a manger? Is there more than one manager? W need more detail here.

Comment: Edited the question @tpet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the schemas. I did modify the employee table to include a manager bit flag which makes the query a bit easier. This doesn't exactly reproduce your desired results, but it is very close. If there is no manager comment on the last plan do you need to include the manager ID? Also, I wasn't sure on the date to include so the date is there for each comment.

```
--Load base tables
CREATE TABLE #Comments 
(EmpFK INT
, PlanFK INT
, Comments VARCHAR(10)
, ModifiedDate DATE)

CREATE TABLE #Plan
(PlanFK INT
, PlanName VARCHAR(10))

CREATE TABLE #Employee
(EmpPK INT
, MgrPk INT NULL
, Mgr BIT
, EmpName VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Comments VALUES (60,7,'empCmnt1','2016-04-13')
INSERT INTO #Comments VALUES (61,7,'mgrCmnt1','2016-04-14')
INSERT INTO #Comments VALUES (60,7,'empCmnt2','2016-04-18')
INSERT INTO #Comments VALUES (61,7,'mgrCmnt2','2016-04-19')
INSERT INTO #Comments VALUES (60,8,'empCmnt1','2016-03-01')

INSERT INTO #Plan VALUES (7,'Name1')
INSERT INTO #Plan VALUES (8,'Name2')

INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES (60,61,0,'user1')
INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES (61,null,1,'mgr1')

--Load Temp table with the last comment per employee per plan

CREATE TABLE #LastComment (EmpFK INT, PlanFK INT, Comments VARCHAR(10), ModifiedDate DATE, Mgr BIT)

INSERT INTO #LastComment
    SELECT Comment.EmpFK, Comment.PlanFK, Comment.Comments, Comment.ModifiedDate, Emp.Mgr
    FROM #Comments as Comment
    JOIN (SELECT c.EmpFK, c.PlanFK, MAX(c.ModifiedDate) as MaxCommentDate
        FROM #Comments as c
        GROUP BY EmpFk, PlanFk
        ) as LastComment on Comment.EmpFK = LastComment.EmpFK AND Comment.PlanFK = LastComment.PlanFK AND Comment.ModifiedDate = LastComment.MaxCommentDate
    JOIN #Employee AS Emp on Comment.EmpFK = Emp.EmpPK


SELECT EmpLC.EmpFK, MgrLC.EmpFK, EmpLC.Comments, MgrLC.Comments, EmpLC.ModifiedDate, MgrLC.ModifiedDate, P.PlanFK
FROM #Plan AS P
LEFT JOIN #LastComment AS EmpLC ON P.PlanFK = EmpLC.PlanFK AND EmpLC.Mgr = 0
LEFT JOIN #LastComment AS MgrLC ON P.PlanFK = MgrLC.PlanFK AND MgrLC.Mgr = 1
```

Comment: Hi tpet, Im new to T-SQL and Im confused as to why you assigned two aliases on one particular table. Can you provide a reference on where this can be used? thanks

Comment: Hi @rk13, both #Employee and #Comments are each used and aliased twice because there is a self join for #Employee to return the Manager - Employee relationship. Then since both employees and managers have comments, #Comments is used twice.

Comment: @tpet My bad.. I did not mention the schema of the tables used. Your answer did point me in a good direction but I missed out to mention a point. The latest employee and manger comments for each plan is the expected result. That would be a group by on the plan ? I am new to this and in the learning stage.

Comment: Does the updated query work for you?